# android change layout dpi

Tags: android, android-layout

can I change layout dpi that use my application on device?

(on developed application that works fine but on small screen size devices everything looks big )

Comment: Of course you can. Just add `dp` suffix to size value wherever you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to supply resources for all the screen size buckets:

```
/drawable/ (default images)
/drawable-ldpi/ (small dpi screens)
/drawable-mdpi/ (medium dpi screens)
/drawable-hldpi/ (large dpi screens)
/drawable-xhdpi/ (xtra large dpi screens)
```

See here for help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

and here for a list of devices using which DPI bucket: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 0):

You need make images for all DPI screen so that it is supported by all types of devices.
Android automatically sets these images for your application according to your device DPI.
Please be sure of all of your resources and see [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Its an layout issue ,Try to use relative layout and linear layout for placing the objects in xml.And for images use .png extension and use nine patch images ,so that it fits in all screen,this will support most of the screens